# Hide a section of the navigation menu on mobile and get mobile stylesheets to work

Tags: html, css

My website has a five-section navigation bar on desktop and it's supposed to have four visible sections on mobile. I cannot get my mobile style sheets to work at all, and I don't know how to hide only the last section of my nav bar and its child.

In every page I have linked the three style sheets:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (max-width: 767px)" href="css/small_device.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="only screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 959px)" href="css/medium_device.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css"/>
```

And in the style sheets themselves I tried to make it so the navigation I wanted hidden was hidden by adding this:

```
.vendors {
display: none;}
```

instead of what was originally there:

```
.drop_menu {
background:#000000;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
padding:0;
margin:0;
list-style-type:none;
height:150px;
}

.drop_menu li { 
float:left;
}

.drop_menu li a {
padding:10px 30px;
display:block;
color:#FFFFFF;
text-decoration:none;
font:1em arial, verdana, sans-serif;
}

/* Submenu */
.drop_menu ul {
position:absolute;
left:-9999px;
top:-9999px;
list-style-type:none;
}

.drop_menu li:hover { 
position:relative; background:#0a208d; 
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul {
left:0px;
top:30px;
background:#0a208d;
padding:0px;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a {
padding:5px;
display:block;
width:170px;
text-indent:15px;
background-color:#0a208d;
}

.drop_menu li:hover ul li a:hover { 
background:#000000; 
}
```

because in the navigation I have it as

```
<div class="drop">
<ul class="drop_menu">    
    <li>. . . </li>
    <li>. . . </li>
    <li>. . . </li>
    <li>. . . </li>
    <li><a href="vendors.html" class="vendors">Vendors</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="register.html" class="vendors">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Sorry if I missed an already-answered post about something like this but I've been searching for hours and couldn't find much. What I did find told me to link the stylesheet(s) and use the @media thing. I don't know where I'm supposed to put the @media blah blah {} and when I did try to put it in the style sheets it didn't do anything. Help?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to consolidate everything into one stylesheet, the proper way of using the `@media` is the following:

```
@media screen and (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 767px) {
  .vendors {
    display: none;
  }

  /* Styles for both max-width 767px and min-width 768px */

}

@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {

  /* Styles for max-width 767px */

}

@media screen and (min-width: 768px) {

  /* Styles for min-width 768px */

}
```

If you want to hide all of `<li>` for the particular screen resolution, the `vendors` class should be on the `li` tag and not the `a` tag.

Comment: Thank you! I figured out the other thing. I had to change the class="vendors" to id="vendors" and that fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

So, I've never actually seen a stylesheet included in the way that you have done it, and it may well be correct.

It could just be the case that you're missing the following meta tag in your

```
<head>
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
```

However, the way I do (and it may not be better at all!) is to simply put:

```
@media screen and (max-width: 300px) {
      /*code*/
}
```

within your usual style.css (BELOW all previous CSS); or include a secondary stylesheet (e.g. responsive.css) again BELOW your desktop style sheet.